# Netgear DG834Gv3 ADSL router dropping Rackspace VPN connection intermittently

Tags: networking, router, vpn, isp

I have a Netgear DG834G v3 ADSL router which I have had since early-2007.

When I work from home I connect to office networks on a Windows 7 machine via a Rackspace-provided VPN using Cisco System VPN Client 5. It works well, except for one issue that is costing me time every working day.

I get intermittently disconnected from the VPN, without any warning or apparent reason.

Since I bought the router 5-6 years ago I have had no need to update firmware, so other than ISP configuration I have had no need to change the router at all and I can say it's worked well for me.

What would be the reason for my VPN connection dropping? Is this an ISP issue (my ISP is Carphone Warehouse/TalkTalk) that I have to take up with them or is it more likely a hardware problem with my router or a VPN configuration issue?

My instincts are to not look into VPN config at the moment as I know a colleague who uses the same VPN through a different router and their ISP can stay connected for hours, even overnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this was happening was due to a timeout configured at Rackspace's end on the VPN connection. It was set to 30 minutes and my connection was dropping after that time was hit.

I could not adjust the timeout setting, so I had to submit a support request to Rackspace who (very quickly) changed it for me.